# C# webrequest returning strange characters mixed in with html code

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I have some code that fetches searches from google and I just noticed recently the html retrieved contains extra characters compared to a web browsers response. I noticed google seems to be forcing https which might be the issue. If someone could help me figure out something I'd appreciate it.

```
        URL = "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=test";

        HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        myRequest.Proxy = null;
        myRequest.Method = "GET";
        myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0";
        myRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        myRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        myRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
        WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        myResponse.Close();

        TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\google.html");
        tw2.WriteLine(result);
        tw2.Close();
```

Here is a comparison between the result from the code and my web browser. First one is from the code, notice the â€Ž near the end. (The other slight difference doesn't effect anything and is probably because of different headers or something.)

```
Speedtest.net by Ookla - The Global Broadband Speed <em>Test</em></a></h3><div class="s"><div><div class="f kv" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_md"><cite class="visurl">speedtest.net</cite><cite class="visurl"></cite></cite>â€Ž<div 

Speedtest.net by Ookla - The Global Broadband Speed <em>Test</em></a></h3><div class="s"><div><div class="f kv _xu" style="white-space:nowrap"><cite class="_md">www.speed<b>test</b>.net/</cite>‎<div
```

Comment: maybe you should fiddle with your "Accept-Charset" and see what you get back with a simpler charset, like utf-8

Comment: That doesn't effect the outcome.

Comment: You're assuming (with your StreamReader) that the response is UTF-8 - is that actually the case?  What are the response headers?

Comment: How I can I check the response headers? They are not included in the result and I basically copied/pasted this code from somewhere so I don't know the ins and outs of it. Also it used to be UTF-8 not that it matters much since something obviously changed.

Comment: HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myRequest.GetResponse(); - with that change, you can get myResponse.CharacterSet and myResponse.ContentEncoding http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well the character set is UTF-8 and content encoding is blank. Thanks for the help with this.

Comment: Well something doesn't seem right now. I'm giving up on fixing the http response and just trying to get rid of those characters. But I can't replace them out.

Console.WriteLine("</cite>â€Ž<div".Replace("â€Ž", "")); Works fine
result = result.Replace("â€Ž", ""); Doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0):

Something bad with your regex. It's totally normal to have non-ANSI characters in Unicode response. You must expect to have they also. We are living in Unicode epoch now. They must be here - because they are present in Google's response. And t's not a bug, it's a feature. :)

There is absolutely nothing wrong with WebRequest.

Comment: I would like to disagree that nothing is wrong. Those extra characters are not in any request I make with a browser. Also they are visible when you view the webpage that is saved and I doubt google has a new hobby of putting random characters in it's webpages now.

The issue here is the difference between the response for a web browser and the code, which in the past were nearly identical.